# How do I batch resize elements?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

I made the first of these white cells, then wished to duplicate down to fill the rest of the screen. Predictably, it didn't fill the space exactly, so I needed to try to resize all of the boxes at once. I selected them all then transformed them at once by stretching the box at the top and the bottom, but now it seems they are all of different sizes.

If this is not the correct method, how does one go about resizing a bunch of elements uniformly?

Secondly, is the method any different if one would wish to include other elements (e.g. In this case, the text) in the resize?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of an automated way. But a relatively easy way would be to get the total height of the available area in pixels and divide by 5.

Select an individual element and go to Edit > Transform > Scale.

You can now just dial in the appropriate height measurements into the following box at the top:
[image]
Where my image shows 50px, by default it shows percentage %, but typing a number followed by px will force it to pixels. Just use the number that you calculated above for the height.